# Formula for Row Number will Change Itself When Table Expands

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I've been using a formula to create row numbers for an expanding table at Column A, with the formula beginning as

```
=IF($C2="","",COUNTA($C$2:$C2))
```

The situation can be recreated when:

1. I Have a number of rows in the table, lets say 10 (therefore, C2 to
   C11 is filled)
2. At column A, at the end of this table in the example, the formula at
   A11 should be

   ```
    =IF($C11="","",COUNTA($C$2:$C11))
   ```
3. I type a number outside of the table, at C12
4. The table auto expands
5. But Now, look at A11 and A12.....why are their formulas
   identical?
6. Also, A11's font was changed on its own

This made me unable to quickly expand the table without manually filling down the formula for column A every time I expand the table. Can anyone point me to the right direction to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any irrelevant data *under* your table, you can try passing the whole column to `COUNTA()` formula:

```
COUNTA($C:$C)
```

Comment: Thank you!

However, I do. I actually have 2 tables on the same page